# In dotnet How many characters in a console column

Tags: c#, .net

In this msdn post it says Console.WindowWidth is measured in "columns" how many characters fit in one column?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.windowwidth(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 1. However, I have to add more characters to post this comment, ironically.

Comment: There is 1 character per column.

Comment: Someone tried to close this as "too broad"? Seriously? Sheesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is 1 character per column

Answer (score 0):

Some characters such as U+0FF0F FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS are two columns wide, e.g. try:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// put Console into UTF-8 mode
Process chcp = new Process();
chcp.StartInfo.FileName = "chcp.com";
chcp.StartInfo.Arguments = "65001";
chcp.Start();
chcp.WaitForExit();

char chr = '／'; // U+0FF0F FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS
Console.WriteLine($"1234\na{chr}b"); // ／ takes two columns
Console.ReadKey();
```